Do I need a German D Visa to move for a PhD in Bonn while holding a French VLS-TS visa?
This August 2024, I moved to France to join my spouse, who is French. I hold a French D visa (long-stay visa, VLS-TS). After entering France, I immediately validated my visa, so now it acts as a residence permit until May next year. My nationality is Indian.
A few weeks ago, I received a PhD offer from the University of Bonn in Germany, and they have sent me a hosting agreement.
My question is: Do I need to apply for a German D visa to move to Bonn, or can I travel there on my French D visa, search for accommodation, and then apply for the German residence permit at the Foreigner's Office (Ausländerbehörde) in Bonn?

As long as you dont hold a Blue Card or Permanent Residency you will need to go for a D-Visa for Germany first. This needs to be done at the German embassy in France. To be sure: ask University of Bonn for support! Universities usually got a visa/international support center for researchers from abroad.
